# remotewebdriver configure one node per browser?

Tags: remotewebdriver

I want to run my tests on a remote vm by using selenium grid
the vm has different browsers so my question is: is it necessary to start a node for every single browser?

Answer (score 0):

No its not required ! Using single command you can start node for all browsers.